# What is $\int_x^{2x}f(t)/t\,dt$?

Tags: limits, functions, definite-integrals, continuity

Let $f\in C^0(\mathbb R)$,

What is :
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\int_x^{2x}\dfrac{f(t)}{t}\,dt$$

I found that : $\forall x\in\mathbb R, \int_x^{2x}f(t)/2x\,dt\le\int_x^{2x}f(t)/t\,dt \le \int_x^{2x}f(t)/x\,dt$.

(It only works if $f$ is non negative.)

We can show that $\int_x^{2x}f(t)/x\,dt = \int_1^{2}f(ux)\,du \to f(0)$ when $x\to0$.

But it doesn't even end into finding if such limit exist.

Have you got some ideas ?

Comment: The inequality ("I found that") requires $f$ to be non negative.

Comment: True, I'll add it !

Comment: Think about using MVT.

Comment: The limit is $\log(2) f(0)$

Comment: Oh I see now ! Thanks !